# Haskell -> Printing sortBy list - error: parse error on input ‘print’

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, ghci

I was trying to run this program on ghci, where it reorders the names in the ascending order of their last names. However, when I run it, I get this error **" error: parse error on input ‘print’ "**. 
 I would truly appreciate it if you can help me out with this. Thank you![enter image description here][1]

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()

names = [("Tatsunori", "Ono"), ("Kishore", "Palanisamy"), ("Calder", "Hosgood"), ("Yiling", "Zhuang")]

main = do
 let compareLastNames name1 name2 = if lastName1 > lastName2
                                      then GT
                                      else if lastName1 < lastName2
                                            then LT
                                            else EQ
   where lastName1 = snd name1
         lastName2 = snd name2
   
   print (sortBy compareLastNames names)
```

Comment: The reason is the `where` that is indented at the same level of the `let`, and not more indented than the `compareLastNames` function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you! That fixed the error mentioned. However, I now got a different error... Do you know how can I fix this? ->
"Unexpected do block in function application:
        do let compareLastNames name1 name2
                 = ...
                 where
                     ...
    You could write it with parentheses
    Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?
  |
7 | main = do
  |        ^^..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the `where` that is indented at the same level of the `let`, and not more indented than the `compareLastNames` function.

You can indent this with:

```
main = do
    let compareLastNames name1 name2 = if lastName1 > lastName2 then GT else if lastName1 < lastName2 then LT else EQ
            where lastName1 = snd name1
                  lastName2 = snd name2
    print (sortBy compareLastNames names)
```

But you make this too complicated, you can work with [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
import Data.Function(on)

main = print (sortBy (compare `on` snd) names)
```

or use [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn):

```
import Data.List(sortOn)

main = print (sortOn snd names)
```